# How can I accumulate string values ​in useState as an array value in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I created a value called degrowth LengthImg with the useState array. When the deleteImgfunc function is executed, the value is entered as a string value. if deleteImgfunc excuted The first may contain a "buger" value, if deleteImgfunc excuted second time "pizza" value may come in.

At this time, I want to store string values ​​in degrowthLengthImg as an array.

like this
expected answer

```
    degrowthLengthImg = ["buger", "pizza"]
```

so i made my code but it comes out like blow

```
   degrowthLengthImg = ["b", "g", ....]
```

this is my code

```
    const [degrowthLengthImg, setDegrowthLengthImg] = useState([])

    const deleteImgfunc = useCallback((value: string) => {
            setDegrowthLengthImg([...degrowthLengthImg, value]);

    }, []);

 return(
     <Pressable style={farmDiaryViewWrapperStyle.imgcloseBtn}
     onPress={() => 
    deleteImgfunc?.(v?.name)}
    >
      )
```

How can i fix my code?

Comment: Can you show the code where you call that function ?

Comment: Do  you want to remove the first item of the array every time the function is called?

Comment: @Debashish no i want to accumulate value data in degrowthLengthImg state

Comment: Ok so first, why are you using useCallBack ? A simple function would be great for your case if you just need to push in an array. And I don't see a problem in your function, are you sure that the param v?.name is the good value ?

Comment: @SCHYNSAnthony oh as soon as i remove useCallback this works! then what does the reson useCallback doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following to add value to the array. Do not use the push function to push to an array. Also, the `useCallback` is unnecessary.

```js
    const [degrowthLengthImg, setDegrowthLengthImg] = useState([])

    const deleteImgfunc = useCallback((value: string) => {
           // If you want to add to array
            setDegrowthLengthImg(deg => [...deg, value]);
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use setDegrowthLengthImg as,

```
 setDegrowthLengthImg(degrowthLengthImg => [...degrowthLengthImg, value]);
```